# How does one create this shape in CSS

Tags: css, css-shapes

[image: The Shape in Question.]

Many weeks have been spent trying to find how one could make this shape, it needs to be just this shape, hoping for something no overlays that makes it appear like the shape, but instead just slanting the rectangle.

Comment: Have you tried anything so far? StackOverflow isn't a free code-writing service, and expects you to [**try to solve your own problem first**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592). Please update your question to show what you have already tried, showcasing a **specific** problem you are facing in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I'll do that next time, apologies.

Comment: You needed to do it this time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
#parallelogram {
  margin: 0 auto;
 width: 50%;
 height: 100px;
 -webkit-transform: skew(-30deg);
    -moz-transform: skew(-30deg);
      -o-transform: skew(-30deg);
            transform: skew(-30deg);
 background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="parallelogram">
</div>
```

Comment: `</div>` needs to be fixed

Comment: Fixed. Thanks for attention

Answer (score 1):

```css
#shape {
  width: 300px;
  height: 75px;
  background-color: blue;
  -webkit-transform: skew(-30deg);
 -moz-transform: skew(-30deg);
 -o-transform: skew(-30deg);
  transform: skew(-30deg);
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="shape"></div>
```